# OOP - sql commands inside PHP class

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a website written with procedural PHP and now I'm re-coding it in (at least partly) OOP style so that I can start learning it. It is a simple page displaying several learning courses (title, description, etc) from a database. The admin can add or delete anything so it has to be dynamic.
At first I ran a single line of code:

```
    $courses=$pdo->run("SELECT id,title,description FROM courses WHERE status=1 ORDER BY id")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Course');
$cmax = count($courses);
```

and echoed e.g. `$courses[3]->description` but I felt like I'm doing nothing else but pretending OOP while just using a multidimensional array. Again, it would be ok for the purpose of the website but my question is, in order to get used to OOP logic, can I do it like this: I'm generating a dropdown menu with only the titles and IDs from the database, and after either is clicked, only then I'm creating the object (to get the description, date, teacher, whatever):

```
$obj = new Course($pdo,$userSelectedID);
echo $obj->getTitle($pdo);
$obj->showDetails($pdo); // etc
```

The class:

```
class Course {

    protected $id;
    protected $title;
    protected $description;

    public function __construct($pdo,$id) {
        $this->id=$id;
    }

    public function getTitle($pdo) {
        $this->title=$pdo->run("SELECT title FROM courses WHERE id=?",[$this->id])->fetchColumn();
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function getDescription($pdo) {
        $this->description=$pdo->run("SELECT description FROM courses WHERE id=?",[$this->id])->fetchColumn();
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function showDetails($pdo) {
        echo "<h3>".$this->getTitle($pdo)."</h3>".$this->getDescription($pdo);
    }

}
```

Is this a wrong approach? Is it ok to run sql commands inside a class? Especially when I already had to use some DB data to generate the dropdown menu. I hope my question makes sense.

PS: I've heard passing the PDO object every time isn't the best practice but I'm not there yet to do it with the recommended instance(?)

Comment: Have you looked at any existing libraries (eloquent etc.) which may give you some idea of how these libraries work from a users perspective, which also may give you some insight into how they need to work.

Comment: Actually I am already choking in the amount of information I've come across regarding the subject but your suggestion makes sense. I'll look into existing and available codes but I hope I'll find something rather simple first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good approach is to create model classes for every table you have in your database.
A model contains private attributes corresponding yo your table columns, with associated getters and setters.
For your Course table:

```
class Course {

    protected $id;
    protected $title;
    protected $description;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription($description) {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

}
```

Then, you have the concept of Data Access Objects. You can create an abstract class that will be extended by your data access objects:

```
abstract class AbstractDAO {

    protected $pdo;

    public function __construct($pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    abstract public function find($id);

    abstract public function findAll();

    abstract protected function buildModel($attributes);
}
```

For your course table:

```
class CourseDAO extends AbstractDAO {


    public function find($id) {
        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE id = :id");
        $statement->execute(array(':id' => $id));
        $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $this->buildModel($result);
    }

    public function findAll() {
        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM courses");
        $statement->execute();
        $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $courses = [];
        foreach($results as $row)
            $courses[] = $this->buildModel($row);

        return $courses;
    }

    public function findByTitle($title)
    {
        ...
    }

    public function create(Course $course)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected function buildModel($attributes) {
        $course = new Course();

        $course->setId($attributes['id']);
        $course->setTitle($attributes['title']);
        $course->setDescription($attributes['description']);

        return $course;
    }
}
```

Modern frameworks do this automatically, but I think it is good to understand how it works before using powerful tools like Eloquent or Doctrine

Comment: Now that's brilliant. Thanks mon ami.

Comment: And it finally works! Thanks again. I had to insert connect(): `$this->pdo->connect()->prepare(...)` otherwise it threw an error. I guess it depends on the DB class. In order to get rid of this need I tried to replace connect() function with __construct  but constructors can't have a return value if I understood well.

Comment: Constructors are called when you instanciate the class, it allows you to set the class's internal state and do stuff before using it. So you can't return a value. I don't see why you need to add the connect call, you just pass and instance of PDO to your DTOs, which is already "connected" when you instanciate it with $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "user", "pass")

Comment: Gosh I figured it out, stupid me, DB connection was inside my own DB class (due to a few wrapper functions I intended to use but also I wanted to use classes as much as possible in general). I thought it is the way it's supposed to be. So that's why I had to use a public function (`connect()`) to return $pdo outside its scope. Now I removed the connection from the class and voilá. Just one last question, in order to use `findAll()` do I need to create an object first to call this function? I expected an array as result but var_dump said it was an object (the last one of  foreach loop).

Comment: Ideally you'll have only one instance of each DTOs, so findAll is an instance method. Findall returns an array of instances of the corresponding model.
There is a great tutorial (in french, but you can still read the code samples) showing how to organize a Silex application using DTOS
https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/2560666-evoluez-vers-une-architecture-php-professionnelle-avec-silex/2562686-iteration-4-modelisation-objet-de-lacces-aux-donnees

Comment: Thanks. I'm learning French so two flies in one hit. The tutorial uses the term data access object (which you also mentioned), should I care whether it's DTO or DAO on my level (i.e. getting a grasp on the basics)?

Comment: My bad, I should I've written DAO in the code samples, typo. I'm going to edit my answer

Comment: findAll() works now , the problem was I never thought `foreach` brackets can be omitted, too, so I did not notice it when I added extra lines to the code (and therefore only the first statement was included). But I had to add [] anyway after $courses to make it work. Cheers